# Newbie : Execution error

Tags: java

I am trying to execute Test.class

Code for Test.java

```
package pkg;  
public class Test {        
  public static void main(String args[]) {        
    System.out.println("This is a test");  
  }        
}
```

I compiled Test.java using `javac -d . Test.java`
After which "pkg" directory got created.
Then I did the following

`cd pkg`

`java Test`

At which point I am getting the following error message.

```
C:\Users\varung\J\pkg>java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name: pkg
/Test)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Did you try `java pkg.Test` from within the original directory?

Comment: Please don't post unformatted code

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it this way:

```
javac -d . Test.java
java pkg.Test
```

The `java` command takes a [fully qualified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) class name as its main argument. A fully qualified name in Java includes package declarations (the fully qualified name of your class is `pkg.Test`).

Since `java` also needs a correct directory structure for packages, you must execute the command from the directory you compiled your source to, which in this case is `.`.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Teach them to fish